# Looking for a Regular Expression extension

Tags: regex, powerbuilder

I'm looking for a Regular Expression library I can use in our application, which is written in PowerBuilder (PB has some RegEx functionality, but it's too limited for my needs). Required characteristics are:

- interface: COM or exported functions (can't use exported classes)
- Unicode
- Free
- Production ready

Any suggestions where can I find such a tool?

Thanks,
Eran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This custom (and recent) PowerBuilder library might help: [**Extension PBNI PbniRegex**](http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use VBScript.RegExp OLE object.

```
OLEObject l_ole
l_ole = CREATE OLEObject
l_ole.ConnectToNewObject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

Now you can use RegExp methods. For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx