# Looking for RegEx pattern match code for Powerbuilder Application

Tags: regex, powerbuilder

I would appreciate if any one has RegEx Pattern Match  Code to be used in Powerbuilder application.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, I'd be reluctant to call this "RegEx", but if you have rudimentary pattern matching needs, Match() is the PowerScript function that does this. It has basic operators, but will only tell you **if** you have a match, not **where** in the target string.

If you need something more robust than that, even if it hadn't [already been mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487406/looking-for-a-regular-expression-extension), I'd point you towards [PbniRegex](http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/en.html).

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

If using PB.NET then you can use .NET framework assemblies that have robust RegEx functionality. If not then maybe what Terry mentioned about PBNIRegex, for which I don't have any experience with.