# PowerBuilder - limited regular expressions

Tags: regex, powerbuilder

Acceptable format:

```
0
1,2
1,100,2000,30000
etc...
```

Regular expression:

```
Match(a_s_stat, "^\d+(,\d+)*$")
```

The function returns false. String a_s_stat is: 0,1

How to save correctly a regular expression in PowerBuilder 9.0?

Comment: Try `"^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$"`. Also, you might be interested in a regex extension,  like [BNI PbniRegex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487406/looking-for-a-regular-expression-extension).

Comment: Unfortunately, your proposal does not work. I've tried before in this way. I can not use PBNI PbniRegex - I did not decide about it.

Comment: [Found it](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37783.1250/pdf/dwref.pdf). The parentheses are a culprit! and that means you **cannot use `Match` for your task** because there is no way to define a *group*, a *sequence of characters to quantify*. So, you can only use a simplified "regex" (we call them just *patterns*, not regular expressions) like `^[0-9,]+$`, that will also match `,,,,,,` like strings

Comment: As an option, try to list as many optional sequences as you can: `[0-9]+,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*` - but again there can be matches like `12,,,,,,12,,,`

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve your problem - although not as pleasant as a "real" regex

```
if Match(data, "^[0-9]+$") or &
    ( Match(data, "^[0-9]+[,0-9]*[0-9]+$") and not Match(data, ",,") ) then
    statusText = "<data> is list of integers"
else
    statusText = "Cannot interpret <data> as list of integers"
end if
```